# Expo react native map crashes on standalone iOS app when region/initial region set

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

Standalone ios app crashes on load when I set region or initial region. Without this prop being set it is not crashing and map displays. On ExpoGo it always works.

```
export const INITIAL_POSITION: Region = {
latitude: 24.8607,
longitude: 67.0011,
latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
longitudeDelta: 0.0421};

export const MapScreen = (props: Props): ReactElement => (
<View style={styles.mapContainer}>
    <MapView
        customMapStyle={MapStyle}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        initialRegion={INITIAL_POSITION}
        style={styles.map}/>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
        <Text>Home</Text>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</View>);
```

**expo@49**

**react-native-maps@1.7.1**

**iOS 17.2**